# How can I turn this mess in a single loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to change this long piece of code in a single loop: Please help me.

```
itemAll[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(0)
}, false);
itemAll[1].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(1)
}, false);
itemAll[2].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(2)
}, false);
itemAll[3].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(3)
}, false);
itemAll[4].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(4)
}, false);
itemAll[5].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(5)
}, false);
itemAll[6].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(6)
}, false);
itemAll[7].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(7)
}, false);
itemAll[8].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(8)
}, false);
itemAll[9].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(9)
}, false);
itemAll[10].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(10)
}, false);
itemAll[11].addEventListener('click', function () {
    klik(11)
}, false);
```

I already tried this but it does not seem to work, I really dont get it why:

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemAll.length; i++) {
    var item = itemAll[i];
    item.addEventListener('click', function (item) {
        klik(item);
    })
}
```

Anyway thank you for your time, I hope someone can figure this out for me.

Comment: @Edd that would be a different problem with that suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Related: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)

Comment: Simply use `klik(this)`. No need for overcomplicate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `.forEach()`:

```
itemAll.forEach(function(item, i) {
  item.addEventListener("click", klick.bind(undefined, i));
});
```

Better yet, you could make sure that all the elements you're working with have a common class, and then just bind a single event handler at the document level that handles clicks and checks for the target element's class. (Basically, the "event delegation" thing that jQuery allows.)

Comment: @Webinan correct. But If jQuery can move away from it so can we ;)

Comment: @Webinan that's true; there's a polyfill for it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: @Pointy yes, and if he is using jQuery he already has a polyfill `$.each`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have an error in your loop. From your code I would assume that you should call your `klik()` function on `i` instead of `item`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemAll.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        itemAll[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            klik(i);
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: And when the OP uses this, they will have a problem since `i` will not be the index it was defined in the loop.

Comment: @epascarello You're right, excuse me. Added an update with consideration of closures.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. How can this get 3 upvotes? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @FelixKling Could you clarify what's the problem here? I'm adding a new variable `index` and then pass it to the `klik` function so the closures don't affect this. Doesn't it makes the behavior as expected?

Comment: This did not really fix it.

Comment: Counter question: why are you not using `i` directly? What is the difference between `i` and `index`?

Comment: As far as I understand, when we pass `i` to the function the closure will affect our behavior so when we finish our loop all `klik` will have `itemAll.length - 1` inside them. But when I make a temporary variable it stores inside the value that we need to pass to the function so we will closure what we need and each of `klik` functions will get an appropriate value. What's wrong with my assumptions?

Comment: Lets recap what the issue is: There is a single variable `i`. Every closure refers to that variable `i`. The loop iterates a bunch of times, so `i` will have a value equal to `itemAll.length` at the end. Lets look at `index`. `i` and `index` have both the same scope (JavaScript doesn't have a block scope). I.e. there is a *single* variable `index`. In the first iteration `index` is set to `0` (`i = 0`). In the second iteration, `index` is set to `1` (`i = 1`), etc. When the loop terminates, `index` has the value `itemAll.length - 1`. You created an *alias* for `i`, which has the same problems.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for explanations. If I encapsulate everything inside the loop into `function()` then all of the iterations should have different values inside `index` variable and it should work now, right?

Comment: Yes. By calling a function you are creating a new scope per iteration, essentially simulating block scope.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemAll.length; i++) {
    var item = itemAll[i];

    (function(item)
    {
        item.addEventListener('click', function () {
            klik(item);
        });
    })(item);
}
```

You need to create a new scope or when you will call `klik(item)` `item` will always be equal to the last item.

EDIT: It seems you want to pass `i` as parameter not `item`, replace the `item` parameter by `i`

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a functional programming example, just to share an alternative solution?

```js
function assign_click_event_to_collection(elements){
  assign_click_event_to_element_and_move_to_next(elements, 0);
}

function assign_click_event_to_element_and_move_to_next(elements, index){
  if(index > elements.length) return false;
  itemAll[index].addEventListener('click', function() {
    klik(index);
  }, false);
  assign_click_event_to_element_and_move_to_next(elements, index+1);
}

assign_click_events_to_collection(itemAll);
```